# Pass value to view on create

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Im trying to make a custom view and pass a value when I add it in another item using the xtype. It looks simple because I dont need to use stores or anything like that, its just static values but I cant achieve it :(

My idea is to place this in a component (the parent of my custom component):

```
...
items: [{
    xtype: 'myNewComponent',
    car: 'Renault'
}]
...
```

And then in my custom component get the value:

```
Ext.define('myNewComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'myNewComponent',
    config: {
        items: [{
            html: 'This is my car: ' + this.config.car
        }]
    }
});
```

I think that Im not understanding something, could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to do.

**Firstly**, you must create a the new config in your custom component. Doing this is as simple as adding it into the `config` object of your class:

```
Ext.define('myNewComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'myNewComponent',
    config: {
        car: null
    }
});
```

`null` here is merely the default value if you do not change it when you create the component.

Now we want to use this new config. What you have done will not work as the scope of `this.config.car` is the DOM window. You will need to create the item using a function of your class. You can achieve this by using the new `updateCar` method of your new `car` config. This method is called anytime you update that config. In your case, that is when you first create your custom component.

```
Ext.define('myNewComponent', {
    ...

    updateCar: function(newCar) {
        this.add({
            html: 'This is my car: ' + newCar
        });
    }
});
```

You can find out more about how the config system works here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/class_system